# Python Output to TKinter Entry has Float64

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

I am loading a CSV into a data frame, doing some calculations and then outputting the results to a grid of tkinter Entry boxes.
This all works fine and the output is correct but it has a proceeding '0' and is followed by 'dtype:float64'. The data in the Entry looks like this (xxxx being the only data I want to display):

```
0  xxxxxx dtype:float64
```

screenshot of output tkinter window:

[image: screengrab of output tkinter window]

To put the calculated data into the Entry box, I am using the command:

```
BGO_Yin.insert(0,BGO_Y)
```

Can I remove the extraneous parts somehow, or reformat the output variable?

Comment: What is the type of `BGO_Y`?

Comment: can you also mention what `BGO_Y` refers to

Comment: It is a float64 . It is either an Easting or Northing geographic coordinate of the format    123456.123 or 1234567.123:

Comment: Try `float(BGO_Y)` or `BGO_Y.item()`.

Comment: acw1668 - .item() has fixed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: The .item() has worked but is giving me the Warning message: FutureWarning: 'item' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: Fixed it. I found another post suggesting the following: .iloc[0]

Comment: The suggested answer float(BGO_Y) also works with no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment answers solved the problem with my `Tkinter` GUI.
I have subsequently upgraded to a `PyQt5` QT Desinger GUI, the final code to send the formatted text the text_box in that case is:

```
self.Q_BGO_Y.setText(str(BGO_Y.iloc[0]))
self.Q_BGO_Y.repaint() #repaint to overcome known bug where text is not initially visible.
```